# How do I match a string with any word in the middle, and store it as a variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a bot that defines a word when I ask "what does" + any word + "mean".

I don't know how to match an input with a string that has any word in the middle, and then store that word as a variable.

It should be something like this:

```
whatDoesWordMean = ["what does mean"]

sentance = input()

if any(x in sentance for x in whatDoesWordMean):
    #Stores word as a variable
    #DefineWord()
```

Right now, it only accepts the input "what does mean"

Comment: try to use regex!

Comment: if you are making chatbot so you should not get the desired word by hard the rules, you should start with Entity Recognition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using regular expressions.

For example:

```
import re

expressions = [r"what does (\w+) mean", r"meaning of (\w+)", r"what is (\w+)"]
patterns    = [re.compile(expr, re.IGNORECASE) for expr in expressions]

while True:
    sentence = input("chat: ")
    pattern  = next((p for p in patterns if p.match(sentence)),None)
    if pattern:
        word = pattern.match(sentence).group(1)
        print(word,"means...")
```

output:

```
chat: what is good
good means...
chat: what does IHMO mean
IHMO means...
chat: hello world
chat: meaning of Life
Life means...
chat:
```

If you don't want to use regular expressions, you can work with a prefix-suffix matching approach using string methods startswith() and endswith():

```
expressions = ["what does | mean", "meaning of |", "what is |"]
patterns    = [(prefix,suffix) for e in expressions
               for prefix,suffix in [e.lower().split("|")]]

while True:
    sentence = input("chat: ")
    matches  = [ sentence[len(p):-len(s) or None] for p,s in patterns
                 if  sentence.lower().startswith(p) 
                 and sentence.lower().endswith(s)]  
    if matches:
        word = matches[0]
        print(word,"means...")
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to find not only words, but phrases also would be this:

```
import re

msg = 'what does SO mean'
wordRegex = re.compile(r'what does (.*) mean')
print(wordRegex.findall(msg))
```

Essentially you are looking for everything that is between `what does` and `mean`. By using regular expressions it is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your bot correctly, it will define whatever is between 'what does' and 'mean'.  One solution I can think of is:

```py
whatDoesWordMean = ['what','does','mean']

word_to_define = input()

split_input = word_to_define.split(' ')
definition = None
for word in split_input:
    if word not in whatDoesWordMean:
       definition = DefineWord(word)
       break
```

Of course this assumes you only want to define one word.  Otherwise you could append the definitions to a list or do the following

```py
whatDoesWordMean = ['what','does','mean']

word_to_define = input()

split_input = word_to_define.split(' ')
to_define = ''
for word in split_input:
    if word not in whatDoesWordMean:
       to_define += word
definition = DefineWord(to_define)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this in a quick glance:

```
whatDoesWordMean = ["what", "does", "mean"]

sentence = input()

word_list = [x for x in sentence.split(" ") if x not in whatDoesWordMean]
```

this will give you a list of words that are between `'what does '` and `'mean'` and store it in the variable `word`. You can join multiple words using pyhtons built in `join()` method.

`word = " ".join(word_list)`

But I would suggest using regular expression solutions. they are much more efficient.